# How to navigate with right to left animation between modals in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

If I open a modal (on iOS), and this modal navigates to another modal, I don't get a "right to left" navigation. I have a bottom to top navigation everytime the target is modal, but I just want this behavior on the first openned modal, then, the rest right to left.

How can I make this navigation? It feels weird openning twice from bottom to top.

React Navigation v6

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can review this tutorial [here](https://itnext.io/change-react-native-screen-animation-direction-with-react-navigation-8cec0f66f22)

Or you can use `transitionConfig` for each screen you want.

```
transitionConfig: () => ({
    screenInterpolator: CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal,
}),
```

Comment: About the tutorial, that's not the right modal from iOS. That's the current "card". And about the transitionConfig, I don't have that option available. I can use cardStyleInterpolator.forHorizontalIOS, but if I use it, it won't be a "modal" anymore. It will present as a card. I have added a screenshot of the type of modal I want. Also, I'm using react navigation v6